# How do I solve "AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'documents'" error?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm programming a script to create multiple Google Docs files.

I have followed the Google Docs API Guides:

Quickstart (https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python)
and Creating and managing documents (https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/documents)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

    print("Creating blank Google Docs file")
    title = 'My Document'
    body = {
        'title': title
    }
    doc = service.documents() \
        .create(body=body).execute()
    print('Created document with title: {0}'.format(
        doc.get('title')))
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note:
This website does not display the indentation around "print("Creating blank Google Docs file")" and "return" correctly. That should be indented once and not twice as it is showing here. The block is not part of the "else: print('Files:')" branch.

Instead of creating a Google Docs file I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create-teamwork-sops.py", line 234, in <module>
    main()
  File "create-teamwork-sops.py", line 227, in main
    doc = service.documents() \
AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'documents'
```

Comment: The reason of your issue is that `service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)` cannot be used for `documents().create()`. So in your case, in order to use `documents()`, how about adding `serviceDoc = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)` and modifying to `doc = serviceDoc.documents().create(body=body).execute()`? From your script, I cannot understand about `SCOPES`. So also please be careful the scopes. If this was not the solution of your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Tanaike, thank you very much for your comment! Unfortunately it doesn't look like 'docs' works here. This line: "serviceDoc = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)" returns nothing in serviceDoc and the script crashes further with error "local variable referenced before assignment". The funny thing is the code I am using originally and which I posted here is a copy paste from the Google Drive API Reference/Guide. I thought Google was supposed to be on top of things like that lol.Their own code doesn't work.

Comment: I have replaced "documents()" with "files()" on line "doc = service.files() \.create(body=body).execute()" and now am getting error "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes". To me that's progress lol. I will try to see if adding the permissions will fix this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About the scope for using Docs API, you can see it at [here](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create).